# Removing views from UIScrollView

Tags: cocoa-touch

I have two UIScrollViews that I move images between. The user can drag and forth between the scroll views. I am trying to animate the movement of the image from one scroll view to another. In `-touchesMoved` (handled in my UIViewController which has two custom UIScrollViews that intercept touch and sends to my UIViewController), I am trying to set the "center" of my UIImageView that is being moved. As it is moved, the image gets hidden behind the UIScrollView and not visible. How do I make it appear on top of the UIScrollView? I am able to handle the `-touchesEnded` properly by animating in the destination scroll view.

I am also confused about `-convertPoint:fromView:` usage in the iPhone Programming Guide (See Chapter 3, Event Handling). If the touch coordinates are in window coordinates, to change my view (UIImageView inside a UIScrollView which is inside a UIView and inside a window) center don't I have to use `-convertPoint:toView:`, i.e.,

```
imageView.center = [self.view.window convertPoint:currentTouchPosition toView:imageView];
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method - (void)bringSubviewToFront:(UIView *)view for making the image view the front most view.

Johan

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you structured your views. If both scrollviews and the imageview are at the same level, it should work. If the imageview is a subview of one of the scrollviews, you can try bringing the scrollview to the front. That way also the imageview will be drawn over the other scrollview.

Johan

Answer (score 0):

I have a View Controller with two ScrollViews. Images are added as subviews. ScrollViews are already in the front. I tried bringing scrollview to the front and also imageview of the scrollview to the front. But somehow when i drag, the center of the image goes over my other scrollview2 which i also tried sending back. But does not seem to work. Here is what i do, in TouchesMove (inside a ViewController)

view= [[scrollView1 subviews] objectAtIndex:currentImageIndex];

[self.view bringSubviewToFront:scrollView1];

[scrollView1 bringSubviewToFront:view];

[self.view sendSubviewToBack:scrollView2];

scrollView1 and scrollView2 are two scrollviews that are part of the ViewController's view.
Does this make sense ?

thanks
mohan